# Copied image does not save PHP symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, controller

I am trying to save an original and a copy of an image that gets sent from a form. I use 2 variables for it, first one stores original, second one is meant to store the copy. I have tried clone, copy and getting the data again, nothing works.

```
        $album = new Album();

        $form = $this->createForm(CreateAlbumType::class, $album);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();

            $albumName = $album->getAlbumName();
            $coverFile = $form->get('cover')->getData();
            $coverFilePreview = clone $coverFile;
```

above this is the initiating part of the controller that works with form data

```
            $currentYear = date('Y');
            $currentMonth = date('m');
            $currentMonthPreview = $currentMonth . '_preview';
            $uploadDirectoryMonth = 'images/' . $currentYear . '/' . $currentMonth; 
            $uploadDirectoryPreview = 'images/' . $currentYear . '/' . $currentMonthPreview;

            if (!is_dir($uploadDirectoryMonth)) {
                mkdir($uploadDirectoryMonth, 0755, true);
            }

            if (!is_dir($uploadDirectoryPreview)) {
                mkdir($uploadDirectoryPreview, 0755, true);
            }



            $newFilename = $imageNumber . '.' . $coverFile->guessExtension();
            $newFilenamePreview = $imageNumber . '_preview.' . $coverFilePreview->guessExtension();
            $coverFile->move($uploadDirectoryMonth, $newFilename);
            $coverFilePreview->move($uploadDirectoryPreview, $newFilenamePreview);


            $album->setAlbumName($albumName);
            $album->setCoverPath($uploadDirectoryMonth . '/' . $newFilename);
            $album->setCoverPathPreview($uploadDirectoryPreview . '/' . $newFilenamePreview);


            $entityManager->persist($album);
            $entityManager->flush();
```

above this is the ending part of the controller, I cut some small parts of the code off because I think that the problem lies somewhere in these parts of the code

I have tried copying the original variable by the second one, Ive tried cloning and geting the data again. These are the only options that made sense to me. The point of this is for the coverFilePreview to have the same image, but independent and with the ability to modify it, like changing size or name, saving it in a different directory, without affecting the original

Comment: PHP puts the sent file as an actual file in the temporary directory by default. What you get from the symfony form is *at most* a reference to that file. `move` will then move that file. The cloned version is not a copy of the file, but a copy of the reference. It will still reference the original and thus will be "empty" or "lost". If you want a file twice, your first action should be to copy it (the file, not the reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly cloning the `$coverFile` object, which represents the uploaded file, you should create a new instance of `UploadedFile` with the same file path.

```php
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();

    $albumName = $album->getAlbumName();
    $coverFile = $form->get('cover')->getData();
    // Remove:  $coverFilePreview = clone $coverFile;

    // Create a copy of the uploaded file
    $coverFilePreview = new UploadedFile(
        $coverFile->getPathname(),
        $coverFile->getClientOriginalName(),
        $coverFile->getClientMimeType(),
        $coverFile->getSize(),
        true, // replace
        true  // autoDelete
    );

    // Rest of your code...
}
```